# How to display an image in C# or VB when the name is in a database?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, image

How can I display an image in C# or VB when the name is in a database?

I am using visual studio 2008 VB or C#

I want to display an image on a windows form
The image name is in a SQL2005 Database
The image is stored in a directory structure.

Ideally I would also like to be able to browse a directory
select an image and add the image name to SQL2005
and add the image into the directory structure for new records

Comment: Sooner or later, someone's going to ask 'What's the question?'

Answer (score 3):

in C#, use a PictureBox... Then to load the image you can use:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\filename.jpg");
```

replace the file name and path with the value loaded from the database